# Presenting a sheet with a button in a navigation stack SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

whenever I present a sheet from my details page which is a naviagtion stack, it dismisses the navigation stack which I do not want it to do. How do I prevent this?

**Tabbar**

This is a Tabbar with the homeView init

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        switch selectedTab {
        case 0:
            NavigationView {
                HomeView(hideTabbar: $hideTabbar, selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeView**

```
var body: some View{
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15, pinnedViews: [], content: {
            ForEach(sections, id: \.date) { section in
                Section(content: {
                    ForEach(section.trips, id: \.id) { trip in
                        NavigationLink {
                            DetailView(tripState: $tripState)
                        } label: {
                            ActivityRowView(trip: trip)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }, header: {
                    Text(section.date)
                })
                Divider()
                    .padding(.top, 0)
            }
        })
        .padding(.top, 5)
    })
}
```

**Detail View**

```
var body: some View{
            ZStack {
               Button(action: {
                        showingSheet.toggle()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("SELECT")
                                .frame(height: 40)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                                
                            
                            
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                                .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(4)
                        
                        
     }.background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground).opacity(0.6))
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                           SheetView()
                        }
        }
```

Comment: What does "dismisses the navigation stack" mean? Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: "...the navigation stack" is the important part of the question,
but you don't show any code about it. Why?

Comment: It’s a detail page. That’s why I said navigation stack.

Comment: I see, your details page is a `navigation stack`, which I assume you mean is wrapped within 
a `NavigationView`. So how to you get to your details page?
Is that also in another `navigation stack`? It would be easier if you just show us the code you use, a `minimal reproducible example`, as mentioned, than us guessing what you have done.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code, however, 
could you just show a working `a minimal reproducible example`, so we 
can replicate your issue.
Is the Tabbar part of a TabView? is the NavigationView inside a tabItem?